# Different behaviour in PowerShell 5/7 when using command of installed module

Tags: powershell, module

I installed 2 versions of a demo module in Windows PowerShell and in PowerShell 7 with the new PSResourceGet module. However a different module is loaded when i execute a cmdlet.

PowerShell 7:

[image]

Windows PowerShell:

[image]

Why is the default behaviour different and is Import Module -Version [...] the only way to prevent this in PowerShell 7?

(The problem persists even if i start new sessions)

Comment: Did you run `Install-Module` twice; once for Windows PowerShell and once for PowerShell Core? What happens if you start a new console for each. Please do not post pictures of text.

Comment: Yes, i ran `Install-PSResource` twice. Once for Windows PowerShell and once for PowerShell Core.

Comment: Another problem is that i cannot import an older module in Windows PowerShell with
`Import-Module DemoModule -Version 1.0.0`. The newer version always will be used.

Comment: After starting a new console, does `Get-Module` report the exiting module? If it does, use `Remove-Module` on it. Is the module in `Get-Module -ListAvailable`? If so, use `Uninstall-Module` until it is gone.

Comment: @rubgra, re Windows PowerShell: the `-Version` parameter is an alias for `-MinimumVersion`; try `-RequiredVersion` instead (version must be an exact match).

Answer (score 0):

The latest non-beta version of Powershell 7 is version 7.3.6 that comes shipped with following Package Providers

```
Get-PackageProvider

Name                     Version
----                     -------
NuGet                    3.0.0.1
PowerShellGet            2.2.5.0
```

The latest **PSResourceGet** module you are using does not seem to be part of official release yet? Are there reasons you are already using it over the traditional **Get-Module** commands?

Regarding the behavior of modules when it comes to PS5 vs PS7, the following information might help you.

- Modules are loaded automatically since Powershell 3 when a function/cmdlet from that module is called
- for this, the paths defined in **$env:PSModulePath** will get searched

  - two paths can be seen in the environmental variables (sysdm.cpl)
  - Powershell on startup dynamically adds additional ones during the session
  - not all module locations are shared between Powershell 5 and Powershell 7

The following locations are present by default

| Location | Description |
| --- | --- |
| C:\Users\X\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules | CurrentUser modules - Powershell 5 |
| C:\Users\X\Documents\PowerShell\Modules | CurrentUser modules - Powershell 7 |
| C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules | AllUsers modules - Powershell 5 & Powershell 7 (PS7 does not install here, but finds installed modules) |
| C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules | AllUsers modules - Powershell 7 |
| C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules | Reserved for Microsoft system modules - Powershell 5 & Powershell 7 (PS7 does not install here, but finds installed modules) |
| C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Modules | Reserved for Microsoft system modules - Powershell 7 |

From https://info.sapien.com/index.php/scripting/scripting-modules/which-version-does-import-module-import:

> When you use Import-Module, run a command that triggers module
> auto-loading (PowerShell 3.0+), or run a script or module with a
> #Requires -Module directive, W**indows PowerShell does not import the newest version of the module**. Instead, it imports the newest version
> of the module that it finds in the first directory in which it finds
> the module. The order in which it looks for the module is determined
> by the value of the PSModulePath environment variable
> ($env:PSModulePath).