# Can't import PS5 module into PS7

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I've tried this on a few systems so I think it's something with the module itself, but I'm not sure what to look for.

**Code**

```
Import-Module PSWriteHtml -UseWindowsPowerShell -WarningAction Ignore
```

**Error**

> Import-Module: Failed to generate proxies for remote module
> 'PSWriteHtml'. Cannot process argument because the value of argument
> "name" is null. Change the value of argument "name" to a non-null
> value.

**Links to the module**

https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteHTML

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWriteHTML/0.0.158

**Additional info**

One thing is that on my development machine, I didn't need to import the module at all. When I tried to run my script on the target server (Windows Server 2012 R2), I got an error that the cmdlet was not recognized. I also noted that `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` is missing from `$Env:PSModulePath`

```
$Env:PSModulePath -split (';')

C:\Users\swtto\Documents\PowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules
c:\program files\powershell\7\Modules
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Monitoring Agent\Agent\PowerShell\
```

When I inspect the system environment variable, I don't see the other paths, not sure why.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Monitoring Agent\Agent\PowerShell\
```

Comment: Does it work without the -UseWindowsPowerShell parameter? PS5 and PS7 do not share the same module location, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77013053/4742987

Comment: @DavidTrevor It does seem to work without `UseWindowsPowerShell`, but don't I need that for compatibility? I'm confused how this works

Comment: If PS7 cannot find an installed module in its paths, it will then also look in the PS5 paths afterwards and load it from there if present. All by default and automatically. Unless you have a reason to use the compatibility mode, dont https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_windows_powershell_compatibility?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @DavidTrevor I was mistaken, it doesn't work without `UseWindowsPowerShell`